# OS X Lion: Strange screen distortions after awaking from sleep

Tags: osx-lion, display, macbook-pro, distortion

My MacBook Pro seems to show weird screen distortions when it awakes from sleep. I always have to restart for this to fix itself. If I don't, all windows I open will show the same screen distortions and will be barely recognisable. The rest of the OS (like Finder) will look normal until I open a Finder window.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

[image]

Comment: Based off the fact that it's appearing in the screenshot it sounds like it could be a graphics hardware issue to me. You could try running a hard ware test to see if it reveals anything useful. You can find out more about how to do so here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509

Comment: Ran the check, came up with nothing. I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Comment: Same thing happens to me on my 2011 15" MBP. I believe it's simply a bug in Apple's graphic switching (between the integrated and dedicated graphics). Except when this happens to me, it fills up the entire screen and the Mac is stuck in the position until I force shutdown and start back up. Very odd that's it's appearing in a screenshot; that would say it's software, as if it would be hardware, that would never of happened...

Comment: @TaylorJasko Same here. It takes over like an illness. ;P

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should make sure your software is up-to-date.

You can try clearing the NVRAM and PRAM:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379

But if that doesn't work I think Adam Thompson is right - it's a hardware booger. Apple's hardware test does not test for every problem. In this case if it's still covered under warranty I'd make an appointment at the local genius bar.